# replacing multiple values in Pandas Column from combination of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two lists

```
a = ["hi", "hello", "hey"]
b = ["Sam", "dean"]
```

and a dataframe which contains a column `ques`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ques':["<input1> This is <input2>", "<input1> Sir, Do you know <input2>?"]})
```

I want to replace `<input1>` by elements of list `a` and `<input2>` by elements of list `b` and create a set of unique questions.

So my expected output is:

```
['hi This is Sam',
 'hi This is dean',
 'hello This is Sam',
 'hello This is dean',
 'hey This is Sam',
 'hey This is dean',
 'hi Sir, Do you know Sam?',
 'hi Sir, Do you know dean?',
 'hello Sir, Do you know Sam?',
 'hello Sir, Do you know dean?',
 'hey Sir, Do you know Sam?',
 'hey Sir, Do you know dean?']
```

I am fine with either `list` or `pandas column`.

**What I tried**

```
from itertools import product

c = list(product(a,b))

ques = []
for q in df['ques']:
  for i in c:
    temp = q.replace("<input1>", i[0]).replace("<input2>", i[1])
    ques.append(temp)
```

Which giving me expected result but my data is too large, so I am looking for more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `product` and `replace`:

```
dfs = [
    df.replace({'ques': {'<input1>': x, '<input2>': y}}, regex=True)  
    for x, y in itertools.product(a, b)
]
pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

```
                            ques
0                 hi This is Sam
1       hi Sir, Do you know Sam?
2                hi This is dean
3      hi Sir, Do you know dean?
4              hello This is Sam
5    hello Sir, Do you know Sam?
6             hello This is dean
7   hello Sir, Do you know dean?
8                hey This is Sam
9      hey Sir, Do you know Sam?
10              hey This is dean
11    hey Sir, Do you know dean?
```

Comment: Anything to do with products and strings is bound to be slow. This should at least avoid direct iteration and be a bit easier on the eyes.